# Difference between __callee__ and __method__

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

In Ruby, one can use either

```
__callee__
```

or

```
__method__
```

to find the name of the currently executing method.

What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`__method__` looks up the name statically, it refers to the name of the nearest lexically enclosing method definition. `__callee__` looks up the name dynamically, it refers to the name under which the method was called. *Neither* of the two necessarily needs to correspond to the message that was *originally* sent:

```
class << (foo = Object.new)
  def bar(*) return __method__, __callee__ end
  alias_method :baz, :bar
  alias_method :method_missing, :baz
end

foo.bar # => [:bar, :bar]
foo.baz # => [:bar, :baz]
foo.qux # => [:bar, :method_missing]
```

Comment: Nicely said. For those who want a recent example in ruby core (early 2020), here is an example: https://git.ruby-lang.org/ruby.git/commit/?id=d3b28ebc7ac527724831a9fb9ec2f963235f9a21

Answer (score 16):

To paraphrase the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-__method__), `__callee__` is the name of the method that the caller called, whereas `__method__` is the name of the method at definition. The following example illustrates the difference:

```
class Foo

  def foo
    puts __callee__
    puts __method__
  end

  alias_method :bar, :foo
end
```

If I call `Foo.new.foo` then the output is

```
foo
foo
```

but if I call `Foo.new.bar` then the output is

```
bar
foo
```

`__method__` returns `:foo` in both cases because that is the name of the method as defined (i.e. the class has `def foo`), but in the second example the name of the method the caller is calling is `bar` and so `__callee__` returns that.

Comment: I wasn't aware of alias_method, so unless this was used they would always return the same value?

Comment: I think aliasing (via alias or alias_method) is the only time they can be different.

Answer (score 9):

**__method__** returns defined name, and **__callee__** returns called name.
They are same usually, but different in a aliased method.

```
def foo
[__method__, __callee__]
end
alias bar foo
p foo #=> [:foo, :foo]
p bar #=> [:foo, :bar]
```

[link](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4415281#new)