# How to dry up an Enumerator in Ruby

Tags: ruby, enumerator

My class has a `File` in it and I want to implement `each_line` with the same feature as `File#each_line` so it can be called with a block or without a block.  When called without a block, an `Enumerator` is returned.

Here is my code currently:

```
  def each_line(&block)
    if block_given?
      read_loop(&block)
    else
      Enumerator.new do |y|
        read_loop(&y)
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def read_loop(&block)
    while line = readline
      block.yield line
    end
  end
```

I'm wondering if there is a more concise idiomatic way to implement each_line rather than asking if a block was passed and doing very much the same thing only slightly different in each case.

`readline` is a public method in the class (which does more what `File#readline` does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is exactly what the [`Object#enum_for`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-enum_for) method is for. It creates an [`Enumerator`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html) from an iteration method that takes a block.

Just put something like this as the first line (after argument validation) of any iteration method you write:

```rb
def each_line
  return enum_for(__callee__) unless block_given?

  while line = readline
    yield line
  end
end
```

Comment: StackOverflow Article about [`__callee__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35391160/difference-between-callee-and-method)